# Use Python to run a javascript in background using Thread

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently working on building a simple word editor using PYQT5 as the main GUI and using Node.js as the text area and do some words filtering stuffs. Here are my code for the PYQT part:

```
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1090, 780)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:3000/"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.webView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets


def loadJS():
    #try to use threading here to run it in background but still no effects

    js = threading.Thread(target=execute_js("../Editor/Engine/index.js"))
    js.daemon=True
    js.start()



def loadGUI():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    loadJS()
    loadGUI()
```

My expected result is using WebView in PYQT5 to load my localhost so I can get something like this:

Expected output

[image]

My Node.js script runs just fine and does all its job, but there's no way to run my main GUI. From my understanding, when run, the system waits for loadJS() to finish its job then call loadGUI(). So I tried to use Threading to put loadJS() into background and keep it running while the loadGUI() in the front. However, it seems to have no effects. I am not sure if I am using Threading wrong or misunderstand its purpose. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial code you are invoking directly in the function in main thread, instead you have to pass as target to the name of the function and in args to the arguments as a tuple.

```
js = threading.Thread(target=execute_js, args=("../Editor/Engine/index.js",))
js.daemon=True
js.start()
```